# how to search for gist by name

Tags: github, gist

Is there a way to find a Gist from the name (or description)?

I was watching a YouTube video discussion and one of the participants brought up a Gist.  It was too small to read on the video, but the name at the top was clear (`dhh/test_induced_design_damage.rb`); however, I wasn't able to use that name to find the Gist.  (Eventually I found a raw link on a Twitter feed, with a 20-digit hex number.  The Gist is public.)  I later tried several different searches to see if there was a way I could find it by name, and I tried looking in Github's Help, but I couldn't find a way.  Did I miss something, or is there just no way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the username you can go to https://gist.github.com/username/ and then search through them, but that only works if it's not an anonymously posted or private gist. There's not a nice way to get to a Gist unless you've got the link if you don't know who posted it.

In your case, the Gist is available as the first one at the moment under https://gist.github.com/dhh.

Comment: Well, of course I do know the username here.  The first thing I tried was `gist.github.com/dhh/test_induced_design_damage.rb` -- fail.  That's when I tried using the different search boxes.  Fail.  It wouldn't have occurred to me to put *just* the username in the URL, and then eyeball for it.  Thanks, it will really help me next time.

Answer (score 1):

prefixes are available eg `filename:*design_damage.rb`

[top result: dhh / test_induced_design_damage.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6g4h.png)

- filename:.bashrc Find all gists with a ".bashrc" file.
- cat language:html    Find all cat gists with HTML files.
- join extension:coffee    Find all instances of join in gists with a coffee
  extension.
- system size:>1000    Find all instances of system in gists
  containing a file larger than 1000kbs.
- cat stars:>100   Find cat gists with greater than 100 stars.
- user:defunkt Get all gists from the user defunkt.
- cat anon:true    Include anonymous gists in your search for cat-related gists.
- NOT cat  Excludes all results containing cat.
- cat fork:only    Search all forked gists for results containing cat.